# Force infrared emittor off in Kinect v2

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Kinect v1 had a property to forcefully put the Infared Emitter off. We have a test-case where the emitter might cause problems / is unwanted.

Is this same property available on the Kinect v2? It has a huge red emitter coming out. Is there a way to put it off?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, in Microsoft Kinect SDK 2.0 it is not possible to turn off the IR emitter.

In [this page from official Microsoft Kinect SDK 2.0 forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/548d7162-2b8c-4937-a98c-b4c14120d0c5/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-the-infrared-emitter-without-closing-the-sensor?forum=kinectv2sdk), I found this:

> Closing all instances of the KinectSensor would be the only way of
>   preventing the emitters from turning on. Remember, Kinect v2 is a
>   shared instance amongst many application; the device is shared. The
>   runtime (KinectService) controls whether the sensor is on/off because
>   it is the only one aware of all applications acquiring data. Basically
>   if you are an application that needs Kinect Data, the only way it
>   knows no application needs the data is for it to close its instance.